# Implementation of constructor for size in stack using array in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Stack {

private:
    int size;

public:
    Stack(int n)
    {
        size = n;
    }
    int stack_arr[size], top = -1;

    void push(int a)
    {
        if (top >= 4)
            cout << "Stack is full" << endl;
        else {
            top++;
            stack_arr[top] = a;
        }
    }
    void pop()
    {
        if (top <= -1)
            cout << "There is no element remaining in stack" << endl;
        else {
            cout << "The popped element is " << stack_arr[top] << endl;
            top--;
        }
    }
    void peek()
    {
        if (top < 0) {
            cout << "Stack is Empty";
        }
        else {
            int x = stack_arr[top];
            cout << "The last element in the Stack is: ";
            cout << x << endl;
        }
    }
    int isempty()
    {
        if (top == -1)
            cout << "Stack is Empty: ";
        else
            return false;
    }
    void display()
    {
        if (top >= 0) {
            cout << "Stack elements are:";
            for (int i = top; i >= 0; i--)
                cout << stack_arr[i] << " ";
            cout << endl;
        }
        else
            cout << "Stack is empty";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Stack s(5);
    s.push(10);
    s.push(12);
    s.push(14);
    s.push(10);
    s.push(12);
    s.push(14);
    s.peek();
    s.display();
    s.pop();
    s.display();
}
```

I'm facing the issue while compilation

```
13:9: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'Stack::size'
14:15: error: from this location
 In member function 'void Stack::push(int)':
21:7: error: 'stack_arr' was not declared in this scope
 In member function 'void Stack::pop()':
28:40: error: 'stack_arr' was not declared in this scope
 In member function 'void Stack::peek()':
38:17: error: 'stack_arr' was not declared in this scope
 In member function 'void Stack::display()':
53:13: error: 'stack_arr' was not declared in this scope
```

can anyone help me for giving idea how i can get stack size from constructor,if im doing wrong approach

Comment: Barring the obvious solution (use `std::stack` and call it done), Regarding, `int stack_arr[size]`, C++ does not allow dynamic sizing in the manner you're attempting. You either need to do the memory management manually, or better: use a dynamic container that does it for you.

Comment: Or use `size` as a template parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made your code compile, you had to do two simple modifications:

```
private:
    int size;
    int* stack_arr;
    int top = 0;
public:

    Stack(int n)
    {
        size = n;
        stack_arr = new int[size];
    }
```

You forgot to define top, also to achieve what you tried with a dynamic array you can use new. I also fixed some issues that lead to random dygits while printing, you basically were going out of array scope:

```
 void push(int a) {

    if (top == size - 1) // in your code it was top<=4,
    //suppose it was only for your specific test case 
    // your forgot that it has to be generic
        cout << "Stack is full" << endl;
    else {
        top++;
        stack_arr[top] = a;
    }
}
void pop() {
    if (top == -1)
        cout << "There is no element remaining in stack" << endl;
    else {
        cout << "The popped element is " << stack_arr[top] << endl;
        top--;
    }
}
void peek()
{
    if (top == -1) {
        cout << "Stack is Empty";
    }
    else {
        int x = stack_arr[top];
        cout << "The last element in the Stack is: ";
        cout << x << endl;
    }
}
int isempty() {
    if (top == -1)
        cout << "Stack is Empty: ";
    else
        return false;
}
void display() {
    if (top > -1) {
        cout << "Stack elements are:";
        for (int i = top; i >= 0; i--)
            cout << stack_arr[i] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "Stack is empty";
}
```

In modern c++ there is a rule: If you have anything in your class using new, you should make a destructor. And if you create a destructor, you should create copy constructor, and copy assignment operator (Its called rule of 3). For bonus, in this case, at least in my opinion, I also created move constructor and move assignment operator ( likely you wont use then in your case, that's why I say its bonus. It's known as rule of 5).

```
    //Destructor
  ~Stack()
    {
      delete [] stack_arr;
    }
    //copy Constructor
    Stack(const Stack& s)
        :
        size(s.size),
        stack_arr(new int[size]),
        top(s.top)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= top; i++) stack_arr[i] = static_cast<int>(s.stack_arr[i]);

    }
    //copy assignment operator
    Stack& operator=(const Stack& s)

    {
        if (stack_arr != nullptr) delete[] stack_arr;
        size = s.size;
        top = s.top;
        stack_arr = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i <= top; i++) stack_arr[i] = static_cast<int>(s.stack_arr[i]);
        return *this;
    }
    //move constructor
    Stack(Stack&& s) noexcept :
        top(std::move(s.top)),
        size(std::move(s.size)),
        stack_arr(std::move(s.stack_arr))

    {
        s.stack_arr = nullptr;
    }
    
    //move assignment operator 
    Stack& operator=(Stack&& s)noexcept
    {
        if (this != &s)
        {
            if (stack_arr != nullptr) delete[] stack_arr;
            size = std::move(s.size);
            top = std::move(s.top);
            stack_arr = std::move(s.stack_arr);
            
        }
        return *this;
    }
```

Comment: As there is a `new` in constructor, better to add a destructor as well in your answer. Actually it would be best to add other 4 methods as well as per rule of five

Comment: we can in this case stick with rule of 3 imo, I will fix it soon

Comment: Do not forget the delete [] stack_arr in the destructor!

Comment: you never said it was suppose to be a feature, @MiniMik

Comment: Thanks @MichalTurek it was good suggestion and work properly

Comment: @M.ShajieShah please check my newest edit, I corrected few things in your code and now it all should work properly if you copy it.

Comment: The example is wrong in many ways. It would be better to let a `std::unique_ptr` member handle the destructor part. Raw pointers are easy to misuse, as shown in this case: The “move” `operator=` has an obvious memory leak. Either explicitly `delete []` the old array pointed by `stack_arr`, or swap it into the R-value `Stack&&` so that it gets deleted with it. The example **leaks** the old array — which is what a `std::unique_ptr` could have prevented. The copy `operator=` has the same memory leak problem. It’s advisable to set up a `main()` and give the operators a thorough `valgrind` spin.

Comment: [`stack_arr = std:;exchange(s.stack_arr, nullptr)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange). If you exchange all the members, you don't need to test for self move

Comment: @Caleth can you be more specific where?

Comment: that would be in the move assignment, similar thing in move constructor

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek I fixed it, you are right about that one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do [what `std::stack` does](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack), and delegate to an existing container type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Stack {

private:
    std::vector<int> data;

public:
    Stack(std::size_t n) : data(n)
    {
    }

    void push(int a)
    {
        try {
            data.push_back(a);
        } catch (std::bad_alloc) {
            std::cout << "stack is full" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    void pop()
    {
        if (data.empty()) {
            std::cout << "There is no element remaining in stack" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "The popped element is " << data.back() << std::endl;
            data.pop_back();
        }
    }
    void peek()
    {
        if (data.empty()) {
            std::cout << "Stack is Empty" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "The last element in the Stack is: " << data.back() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    bool isempty()
    {
        return data.empty();
    }
    void display()
    {
        if (!data.empty()) {
            std::cout << "Stack elements are:";
            for (int i : data) {
                std::cout << i << " ";
            }
            std::cout << endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Stack is empty" << endl;
        }
    }
};
```